# python: Keep entry in dict synced to the original?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm adding variables (pygame surfaces) to a list like this, used to set in which order my game renders surface layers:

```
self.gameLayers = {
    0: [self.backDrop]
}

def add_layer(self, surface, priority):
    self.gameLayers.setdefault(priority, []).append(surface)

add_layer(self.alphaFadeLayer, 1)
```

Basically, it's added to a list inside a dict, `self.alphaFadeLayer` would now be at `self.gameLayers[1][0]`, which is fine. But now, if I make changes to `self.alphaFadeLayer`, the surface that is drawn to the screen using what is in `self.gameLayers` does not change at all, and comparing the two after the change does show that they aren't equal any more, which they were before the change.
If it matters, this is how I'm editing the surface:

```
# Reset the layer and make it slightly more transparent than before
self.fadeAlpha = max(0, self.fadeAlpha - 1)
self.alphaFadeLayer = self.fadeLayer.copy()
self.alphaFadeLayer.fill((255, 255, 255, self.fadeAlpha), None, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
```

I thought that python didn't actually copy the surface, but simply put a reference to it into my list, am I wrong in thinking that? Does copying another surface (which it was based on to begin with) throw it off?
And how would I achieve it that I can make edits to `self.alphaFadeLayer` and have those changes reflected in the copy in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
alphaFadeLayer = ...
```

you assign to `alphaFadeLayer` reference to new surface and now `alphaFadeLayer` refers to different surface then `self.gameLayers[1][0]`

Probably you should do

```
alphaFadeLayer.blit( self.fadeLayer )
```

Comment: Yup, that worked just fine. Guess I'll just empty the surface and blit the original onto it to reset it from now on, thanks! I think I understand why the old one didn't work.